# Not able to intall mysql module in my nodejs project directory as well as globally

Tags: mysql, node.js, npm

What i tried to is here! But it showed me this.

```
F:\nodeDemo\nodeMysql>npm install mysql
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...":"mysql","version":"'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Nisith Saha\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-11-12T21_29_01_184Z-debug.log
```

**Error Screenshot**
[image]

The error log text file (debug..file ) shows the following. Any suggestion/Solution ? What is wrong here?

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   'mysql'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.12.0
3 info using node@v12.13.0
4 verbose npm-session 98291420349cc4f5
5 silly install loadCurrentTree
6 silly install readLocalPackageData
7 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mysql 858ms (from cache)
8 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for mysql@latest Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...":"mysql","version":"'
9 timing stage:rollbackFailedOptional Completed in 1ms
10 timing stage:runTopLevelLifecycles Completed in 1047ms
11 verbose stack SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...":"mysql","version":"'
11 verbose stack     at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
11 verbose stack     at parseJson (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\json-parse-better-errors\index.js:7:17)
11 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-fetch-npm\src\body.js:96:50
11 verbose stack     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
12 verbose cwd F:\nodeDemo\nodeMysql
13 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17763
14 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "mysql"
15 verbose node v12.13.0
16 verbose npm  v6.12.0
17 error Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...":"mysql","version":"'
18 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me->

```
npm WARN using --force I sure hope you know what you are doing.

F:\nodeDemo>npm cache verify
Cache verified and compressed (~\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_cacache):
Content verified: 0 (0 bytes)
Index entries: 0
Finished in 0.045s

F:\nodeDemo>npm install mysql -g
+ mysql@2.17.1
added 11 packages from 15 contributors in 14.555s
```

Comment: Sorry ,I missed out a line at first i.e ` >npm cache clear --force`